# Calculate min and max from json data and store the result as list

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

I have data in JSON format, the sample is given below. I want to calculate the min and max range for the values inside the variable i.e. align_X, align_Y, align_Z.

```
{"id": 0, "variable": {"align_X": 41, "align_Y": 51, "align_Z": 80}}
{"id": 1, "variable": {"align_X": 0}}
{"id": 2, "variable": {"align_Y": 1, "align_Z": 0}}
```

Desired output is:

```
        "align_X": [
            0.0,
            41.0
        ],
        "align_Y": [
            1.0,
            51.0
        ],
        "align_Z": [
            0.0,
            80.0
        ]
```

Any help is appropriated.
Thank you

Comment: could you please add what you have tried ?

Comment: what is the 0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0 in the output ?

Comment: I have tried converting it to a dataframe and then using the min() and max() function. 
`with open('file', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        data.append(json.loads(line))
    df = pd.json_normalize(data)`

are there any better way to do it without converting it to data frames as I don't need it for further processing? @Suresh

Comment: First value is Minimum i.e. for Align_X its 0 and the value followed by it is the Maximum which is 41. I wrote a desired output.

Comment: var result = test.reduce((acc, cobj) => {
    for (key in cobj.variable) {
        if (acc[key]) {
   if(acc[key] > cobj.variable[key]){
    acc[key].push(parseFloat(cobj.variable[key]).toFixed(2))
   } else if (acc[key] < cobj.variable[key]){
    acc[key].push(parseFloat(cobj.variable[key]).toFixed(2))
   }
  }
        else {
   acc[key] = [];
   acc[key].push(parseFloat(cobj.variable[key]).toFixed(2))
  }
    }
 return acc;
}, []);

Comment: can you try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
    var test = [{
            "id": 0,
            "variable": {
                "align_X": 41,
                "align_Y": 51,
                "align_Z": 80
            }
        }, {
            "id": 1,
            "variable": {
                "align_X": 0
            }
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "variable": {
                "align_Y": 1,
                "align_Z": 0
            }
        }
    ]

    var result = test.reduce((acc, cobj) => {
    for (key in cobj.variable) {
        if (acc[key]) {
            if(acc[key][0] > cobj.variable[key]){
                if(!acc[key][1]){
                    acc[key][1] = acc[key][0];
                }
                acc[key][0] = parseFloat(cobj.variable[key]).toFixed(2)
            } else if(acc[key][1] == undefined || acc[key][1] <  cobj.variable[key]){
                acc[key][1] = parseFloat(cobj.variable[key]).toFixed(2)
            }
        }
        else {
            acc[key] = [];
            acc[key].push(parseFloat(cobj.variable[key]).toFixed(2))
        }
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```

console.log(result);

Comment: Thank you, I checked the JavaScript and it worked, the results are flipped but, i.e. Maximum value is printed first and Minimum after that. `[ align_X: [ '41.00', '0.00' ], align_Y: [ '51.00', '1.00' ], align_Z: [ '80.00', '0.00' ] ]`
I think I can figure it out and thank you very much for the logic part.

Comment: Got it , found other scenario's , so updated the logic.

Answer (score 0):

**My solution**

```
#Your input
d = [{"id": 0, "variable": {"align_X": 41, "align_Y": 51, "align_Z": 80}},
     {"id": 1, "variable": {"align_X": 0}},
     {"id": 2, "variable": {"align_Y": 1, "align_Z": 0}}
    ]

#To store result float(-inf) smallest number in python & float(inf) is largest
output = {
    "align_X" : [float('inf'),float('-inf')],
    "align_Y" : [float('inf'),float('-inf')],
    "align_Z" : [float('inf'),float('-inf')]
}
for item in d:
    for each in output.keys():
        try:
            if item['variable'][each]<output[each][0]:
                output[each][0] = item['variable'][each]
                
            if item['variable'][each]>output[each][1]:
                output[each][1] = item['variable'][each]
        except:
            continue
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the python code @Ujjal, The output here is limited to only 3 variable X, Y, Z, but the actual dataset has more variable, I just posted small sample of it.